# Counting how many decision variables are equal

Tags: c++, variables, counting, or-tools, cp-sat

I'm a beginner user of Google OR-Tools, especially the CP-SAT. I'm using version 9.3, and I'm interested in the C++ version.

I'm modeling a problem where I need to count how many pairs of decision variables have the same (assigned) value. So, let's suppose I have a set of integer variables like this:

```cpp
std::vector<IntVar> my_vars;
```

I also have a set of pairs like this:

```cpp
std::vector<std::pair<size_t, size_t>> my_pairs;
```

Assume that all bounds are valid, size, etc, are valid. Now, I want to compute how many of these pairs have the same value. Using IBM Ilog Concert, I can do it very straightforward using:

```cpp
// Using Ilog Concert technology.
IloIntVar count(env, 0, MY_UPPER_BOUND);

IloIntExpr expr_count(env);
for(const auto& [u, v] : my_pairs) {
    expr_count += (my_vars[u] == my_vars[v]);
}
        
model.add(count == expr_count);
```

Here, `count` is a decision variable that holds how many pairs have the same value in a given solution. The expression is a sum of boolean values comparing the actual decision variable's values, not the variable objects themselves (i.e., is the object representing variable `u` is the same object representing variable `v`).

Using OR-Tools, the equality operator `==`, compares whether the variable objects (or representation of them) are equal, not the decision variable values. So, the following fails by generating an empty expression:

```cpp
// Using Google Or-Tools CP-SAT.
IntVar count = cp_model
    .NewIntVar(Domain(0, my_pairs.size()))
    .WithName("count");

LinearExpr expr_count;
for(const auto& [u, v] : my_pairs) {
    expr_count += (my_vars[u] == my_vars[v]);
}

cp_model.AddEquality(count, expr_count);
```

Note that, according to Google OR-Tools code ([here](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/49b6301e1e1e231d654d79b6032e79809868a70e/ortools/sat/cp_model.h#L171)), we have that:

```cpp
class IntVar {
  //...
  bool operator==(const IntVar& other) const {
    return other.builder_ == builder_ && other.index_ == index_;
  }
  //...
};
```

i.e., comparing if the variables are the same, but not the value assigned to them. Therefore, we cannot compare decision variables directly using CP-SAT, and we need to recur to another method.

Obviously, I can change the model using some big-M notation and linearize such expressions. However, can I do count without to recur to "remodeling"? I.e., is there a construct I can use "more or less" easily so that I address such cases?

I must mention while I only depict one case here, I have quite a few counting variables of several sets like that. So, remodeling using big-M will be a big headache. I would prefer a simpler and straightforward approach like Ilog Concert.

### (Update) Little extension

Now, I want do the same but comparing decision variables with scalars. For example:

```cpp
std::vector<int> my_scalars;

for(size_t i = 0; i < my_scalars.size(); ++i) {
    expr_count += (my_vars[i] == my_scalars[i]);
}
```

While this can be done using Ilog, it even did not compile on OR-Tools.

THanks,

Carlos

Comment: [See "reification"](https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/channeling#c++) which helps introducing countable *boolean-variables*. I guess, Ilog is doing exactly the same, although a lot of this seems to be "hidden".

Comment: Yes. It is as Sasha said. I wrote the code for CPO. :-)

Comment: About your update / *scalar*: This is a common type-safety impl-thing (i remember introducing dummy vars fixed to constants in *gecode* in the past too). or-tools howewer has [model.NewConstant(MY_SCALAR);](https://developers.google.com/optimization/reference/sat/cp_model/CpModelBuilder?hl=en) which should make this easy!. See also [golomb_sat.cc example](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/49b6301e1e1e231d654d79b6032e79809868a70e/examples/cpp/golomb_sat.cc#L59)

Comment: I did not implement the == operator in c++ because in is very invasive in the c++ code and can lead to many errors.

Comment: @LaurentPerron It makes sense and avoids a lot of issues. And then, you can reserve the operator== for internal use. In the very end, the underlying modeling is more or less the same. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

here is a tentative code:

```
IntVar count = model.NewIntVar(0, MY_UPPER_BOUND);

LinearExpr expr_count;
for(const auto& [u, v] : my_pairs) {
    BoolVar is_equal = model.NewBoolVar();
    model.AddEquality(my_vars[u], my_vars[v]).OnlyEnforceIf(is_equal);
    model.AddNotEqual(my_vars[u], my_vars[v]).OnlyEnforceIf(is_equal.Not());
    expr_count += is_equal;
}

model.AddEquality(expr_count, count);
```

Comment: Thanks, Laurent. Indeed, with the help of @sascha, I have done something similar.  Take a look at my answer below. It is very similar to yours, but I save the variables for later use.

Answer (score 1):

With help of @sascha and @Laurent, my solution is this one:

```cpp
vector<BoolVar> is_equal;
is_equal.reserve(my_pairs.size());

for(const auto& [u, v] : my_pairs) {
    is_remainder_equal.push_back(cp_model.NewBoolVar());
    cp_model
        .AddEquality(my_vars[u], my_vars[v])
        .OnlyEnforceIf(is_equal.back());
    cp_model
        .AddNotEqual(my_vars[u], my_vars[v])
        .OnlyEnforceIf(Not(is_equal.back()));
}

cp_model.AddEquality(LinearExpr::Sum(is_equal), count);
```

It is the same as @Laurent in the very end, but I save the boolean vars for late use.

For scalars, it looks like I don't need to make a constant, just compare directly with the expression.

Thanks, @Laurent and @sascha. You guys were very helpful.