# Counting the number of occurrences in an IntVar list in ortools

Tags: python, or-tools, cp-sat

I am trying to solve a kind of an employee scheduling problem. There is a list of employee that works 24 hours shifts, 8 days in a month. I need to reduce the spread of employee count each day, but i am unable to get it to work. Because every employee has a fixed amount of hours working, I can't sum all workers on all days and get the average. The solution i found on theory is something like this:

```py
days_six_employee_working = len([day for day in counts if day["count"] == 6])
days_seven_employee_working = len([day for day in counts if day["count"] == 7])
days_eigth_employee_working = len([day for day in counts if day["count"] == 8])
days_nine_employee_working = len([day for day in counts if day["count"] == 9])
days_ten_employee_working = len([day for day in counts if day["count"] == 10])
weighted_sum = days_six_employee_working**days_six_employee_working
+days_seven_employee_working**days_seven_employee_working
+days_eigth_employee_working**days_eigth_employee_working
+days_nine_employee_working**days_nine_employee_working
+days_ten_employee_working**days_ten_employee_working)

model.Maximize(weighted_sum)
```

but there are two problems with this:

1. I dont know beforehand the list of counts (like, i dont know `[6,7,8,9,10]`)
2. I can't filter the days: `day["count"] == 6`

By the way, this is how I calculate the number of employees each day if its any help:

```py
working = []
for day in range(1, days_in_month+1):
    working.append(sum([employee.shifts[day] for employee in employees]))
```

```py
for employee in employees:
    for day in range(1, days_in_month+1):
        employee.shifts[day] = model.NewBoolVar(f"emp_{employee.name}_day_{day}")
```

I am definitely new to cp-sat, so please point out any better so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I found a solution. Primarily derived from: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133175/counting-how-many-decision-variables-are-equal/72150651)

1. A container for final counts. Because I already knew the number I want to filter I built a dictionary from it.

```py
number_of_occurrences = {
    i: self.model.NewIntVar(0, 31, f"count_of_{i}_days")
    for i in range(
        self.settings["min_people_per_day"],
        self.settings["max_people_per_day"] + 1,
    )
}
```

2. Get the number of people working for all days in a list. I could probably use `model.Add(x == sum(...))` here but nonetheless I didn't.

```py
working = []
for day in self._days_in_month:
    x = self.model.NewIntVar(
        0, len(self._assistant_list), f"number_of_asses_on_day_{day}"
    )
    self.model.AddAbsEquality(
        x, sum([ass.shifts[day] for ass in self._assistant_list])
    )
    working.append(x)
```

3. Key part, filtering. We create a temp. variable named `is_equal`. This will be positive if the current day is equal to the one we are currently filtering for. Then we add it to `count` list and sum that list in the and. As sum takes `True` as 1 and `False` as 0, in the end we got the total of occurrences in the main list.

```py
for key, val in self.number_of_occurrences.items():
    count = []
    for num in working:
        is_equal = self.model.NewBoolVar("is_equal")
        self.model.Add(num == key).OnlyEnforceIf(is_equal)
        self.model.Add(num != key).OnlyEnforceIf(is_equal.Not())
        count.append(is_equal)
    self.model.Add(val == sum(count))
```